# Can't create a AWS Batch JobDefinition JobRoleArn in Cloudformation using a !Ref

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-batch

I'm trying to create a Batch setup in Cloudformation. I have in Resources an IAM Role:

```
  SecretsAndS3AccessRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: batch.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecretsManagerReadWrite'
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess'
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'
```

Then in my JobDefinition I have:

```
  JobDefinition:
    Type: 'AWS::Batch::JobDefinition'
    Properties:
      Type: container
      ContainerProperties:
        Image: public.ecr.aws/l0v4l2q2/rapidtide-cloud
        Vcpus: 2
        Memory: 2000
        Command:
          - /simple-test
        Privileged: true
        JobRoleArn: !Ref SecretsAndS3AccessRole
        ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref SecretsAndS3AccessRole
        Secrets:
          - Name: MY_SECRET
            ValueFrom: arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789:secret:MYSECRET-zSQVSQ
      RetryStrategy:
        Attempts: 1
```

When I try to build the stack, I get:

> An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the RegisterJobDefinition operation: Error executing request, Exception : executionRoleArn bothrefs-SecretsAndS3AccessRole-1INAOWFBH2SK2 is not an iam role arn

If I remove the `ExecutionRoleArn` line and the Secrets, the stack builds fine, which is to say that `JobRoleArn` is happy with a value of `!Ref SecretsAndS3AccessRole`.  (But I need the secrets, and to use secrets you need an execution role.) And if I hardcode the ARN there, it works fine.

What is different about `ExecutionRoleArn` that it doesn't allow a `!Ref`? According to [the documentation for JobDefinition/ContainerProperties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-batch-jobdefinition-containerproperties.html), `JobRoleArn` and `ExecutionRoleArn` seem the same sort of object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!Ref` returns the logical ID of the resource, not the ARN.
[You need to use !GetAtt.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#aws-resource-iam-role-return-values)

This should work:

```
ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt SecretsAndS3AccessRole.Arn
```

Comment: That worked. But why does `JobRoleArn: !Ref SecretsAndS3AccessRole` work? What's different about the two?

Comment: In all honesty I don't know, I would expect it to not work.

Comment: I tested removing JobRoleArn entirely - that makes my job fail. I tested changing it to also be `!GetAtt SecretsAndS3AccessRole.Arn` -- that succeeds. So this is a mystery - JobRoleArn likes it either in Ref or GetAtt form, but ExecutionRoleArn requires GetAtt form.

Comment: By the way, I got that syntax from this AWS Blog article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-cloudformation-to-create-and-manage-aws-batch-resources/ - it creates a stack using that form.

Comment: I guess the IAM Role specification changed over time.